# How to add a tab stop in Word with a center and right alignment?

Tags: microsoft-word, alignment

Specifically, I am trying to use two alignments in a single line in MS Word for purposes of displaying equations (centered) with their equation number (right-aligned). For example:

> ```
>                                        F = ma                                      (13)
> ```

Is this possible in Word? I have seen left alignment and right alignment in the same line, but never center and right alignment.

Also, is there some way to save such a such style to make it easy to apply to all the equations in the document?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

It is certainly possible. Follow these instructions:

1. Open the View tab
2. Activate the ruler
3. From the ruler, click on the tab stop type until you see the "Center-aligned tab stop". The tooltip should tell you all you need.
4. Place the center-aligned tab stop on the horizontal ruler where you need the center-aligned text to appear.
5. Do the same, but this time with a right-aligned top stop.
6. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, type the text that should be center-aligned, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again, and type the text that should be right-aligned.